# Checkbox checked value passed through several php pages

Tags: php, cookies, checkbox, checked, unchecked

So I am trying to create a checkbox that I can pass it's value or have it's value stored in a cookie, so I can use it across several different pages.

Currently I have this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="customLogoCheckbox" name="customLogo" onClick="window.open('vtest.php', '_blank','width=300,height=150,left=25,top=25,scrollbars=yes')" value="Show Active">Use Custom Logo

    <?
    if (customLogoCheckbox.checked == true)
    {
        $_SESSION['logoCheck'] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['logoCheck'] = 0;
    }
```

And it just sets the cookie to 1 and doesn't allow it to change back to zero when I uncheck the checkbox, any ideas?

Comment: you are not adding the php code ``if (customLogoCheckbox.checked == true)`` is a javascript code .. not php

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, still a little rusty/new at web based coding, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
if( isset($_REQUEST['customLogo']) && $_REQUEST['customLogo'] == "Show Active" )
   $_SESSION['logoCheck'] = 1;
else
   $_SESSION['logoCheck'] = 0;
```

First check if customLogo checkbox is set, then check it's value, and if everything is fine then set logoCheck to 1. If customLogo value is not set or it's not "Show Active" then the variable is set to 0 and your choice is reverted.
This is an example of how it works:

```
<?php
//start session
session_start();
//check if form as been submitted
if( isset( $_REQUEST['submit'] ) {
   if( isset($_REQUEST['customLogo']) && $_REQUEST['customLogo'] == "Show Active" )
      $_SESSION['logoCheck'] = 1;
   else
      $_SESSION['logoCheck'] = 0;
}
?>
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <input <? if( $_SESSION['logoCheck'] == 1 ) echo "checked=\"checked\"" ?> type="checkbox" id="customLogoCheckbox" name="customLogo" value="Show Active"> Use Custom Logo<br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ok"/>
</form>
```

Comment: This sounded like an awesome idea, but didn't work either, it was set to zero and would not revert.

Comment: I made some tests and it worked fine, maybe there is something to change into html or javascript. I'll edit this answer adding a little HTML to show how this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply a condition upon the $_POST or $_GET variable, not on some php-unknown customLogoCheckbox.checked kind of variable.

Comment: I understand what you're getting at but how would I do this?